# Rename Custom deb package

Tags: repository, deb, packaging, localrepository, reprepro

How can I rename a .deb package that can be uploaded to reprepro?

For example, I have a deb package `example-latest.deb` which is the latest version, I have created a custom repository so users can download it from there, but there are multiple packages with the same name on the existing ubuntu repos. So basically I want to rename this `example-latest.deb` to something like `myname.deb` so users that use my repository can install the package by typing `apt install myname`

from the deb package, I have ran the following:

```
changestool myname.changes adddeb myname.deb
changestool myname.changes setdistribution ubuntu
gpg --clearsign myname.changes
```

and after looking at the myname.changes I see the package is named something like `example_2.5.1_all.deb` which makes me unable to upload it. I can rename the file to comply with this but then I am not really accomplishing anything.

Anybody knows what is the best way to rename a file?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to extract the .deb to a temporary directory (tmpdir).

```
dpkg-deb -x example-latest.deb tmpdir
```

Then we are going to pull the control file that is located in the tmpdir/DEBIAN/ folder. This is where you will make your dependency changes.

```
cd tmpdir
dpkg-deb --control example-latest.deb
```

Edit the tmpdir/DEBIAN/control file

```
vim tmpdir/DEBIAN/control
```

Change the package name:

```
packages: myname
```

After you have edited your control file you will need to repackage your .deb with this command.

```
dpkg -b tmpdir new-name-of-package.deb
```

Install the package and then you can run

```
dpkg -i new-name-of-package.deb
apt install myname
```

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=35136